# Deleting incremental snapshots before occasional full backup Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, snapshot

Regarding snapshots on Google Cloud Compute Engine, I have some questions I could not find answers to in the documentations:

1. We do have a two-hourly frequency for some of our disks. The documentation says that at not defined times, a full image of the disk is captured. In case I do not need to restore anything from before the latest full image, does this mean that all previous snapshots to the new full image could be deleted?
2. If so, how do I identify the snapshots that can be deleted?
3. Or: Is there even a way to accomplish this task automatically (e.g. something like "delete all prior incremental images after latest full image"?)

Comment: **1**. What do you mean by "We do have a two-hourly frequency for some of our disks."? Could you please point at the documentation where "says that at not defined times, a full image of the disk is captured."? First snapshot contains full image of your disk, all the following snapshots are incremental. Accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots): "Compute Engine uses incremental snapshots so that each snapshot contains only the data that has changed since the previous snapshot."

Comment: **2**. Have you checked  the article [Snapshot deletion](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshots#deletion)? Accordingly to the documentation: "When you delete a snapshot, Compute Engine immediately marks the snapshot as DELETED in the system. However, if the snapshot does have dependent snapshots: 1. Any data that is required for restoring other snapshots is moved into the next snapshot, increasing its size. 2. Any data that is not required for restoring other snapshots is deleted. ". Does it answer your question?

Comment: **3**. you can use [Snapshot retention policy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots#retention_policy): "A snapshot retention policy defines how long you want to keep your snapshots."

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza: thx so much! your comments helped me out! Here's the link to the "occasionally" performed full image backup: [Use existing snapshots as a baseline for subsequent snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#use_existing_snapshots_as_a_baseline_for_subsequent_snapshots).

Comment: *@Peter Sonntag* Thank you! Good catch! I've posted an answer, please accept it if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide you some links to the documentation that could answer your questions:

1. Accordingly to the documentation [Working with persistent disk snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#deleting_snapshot):

> Compute Engine uses incremental snapshots so that each snapshot contains only the data that has changed since the previous snapshot.

on the other hand, as it was admitted by *@Peter Sonntag*,  accordingly to the documentation [Use existing snapshots as a baseline for subsequent snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#use_existing_snapshots_as_a_baseline_for_subsequent_snapshots):

> **Important**: Snapshots are [incremental](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#before-you-begin) by default to avoid billing you for redundant data, to minimize use of storage space, and to decrease snapshot creation latency. However, to ensure the reliability of snapshot history, a snapshot might occasionally capture a full image of the disk.

2. Accordingly to the documentation [Snapshot deletion](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshots#deletion):

> When you delete a snapshot, Compute Engine immediately marks the
> snapshot as DELETED in the system. If the snapshot has no dependent
> snapshots, it is deleted outright. However, if the snapshot does have
> dependent snapshots:
>
> 1. Any data that is required for restoring other snapshots is moved into the next snapshot, increasing its size.
> 2. Any data that is not required for restoring other snapshots is deleted. This lowers the total size of all your snapshots.
> 3. The next snapshot no longer references the snapshot marked for deletion, and instead references the snapshot before it.

3. To automate deletion of the snapshots of you can use [Snapshot retention policy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots#retention_policy):

> A snapshot retention policy defines how long you want to keep your snapshots.
>
> If you choose to set up a snapshot retention policy, you must do so as part of your [snapshot schedule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots).